# unnecessary list created in `github_document` when emojis are used

Tags: r, r-markdown, emoji, readme

I am trying to write an `.Rmd` document for a `GitHub` repo and the relevant text of the doucment looks like the following:

## YAML for the doc-

```yaml
---
title: "trial"
output: github_document
---
```

## Content of the document-

```r
## R Markdown

`r emo::ji("check")` descriptive statistics <br>
`r emo::ji("check")` statistic + *p*-value <br>
`r emo::ji("check")` effect size + CIs <br>
```

If I knit this, I see an unnecessary list is created at the letter *CIs*, and I am not sure why or how to avoid this behavior:

[image]

This problem disappears as soon as I remove `+` before *CI* in `effect size + CIs`. But I'd like to include `+`.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Add a space:

```
---
title: "trial"
output: github_document
---

## R Markdown

`r emo::ji("check")` raw data + distributions <br>
`r emo::ji("check")` descriptive statistics <br>
`r emo::ji("check")` statistic + p <br>
`r emo::ji("check")` effect size + CIs
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Do you mind adding a line or two as to why this works?!

Comment: I have literally no idea, I just guessed. Maybe something to do with how markdown reads to the end of a line?

Comment: Your solution actually doesn't solve this issue. It just postpones the issue. See my updated question.

Comment: That's strange because in my version it doesn't have that problem, try removing <br> from the final item in the list.

Comment: Even if I remove `<br>` from the last line, the issue persists.

Comment: Sorry in which case I can't reproduce it as it worked for me